# Finding best/ close to best outcome from almost random data

Tags: python, algorithm, heuristics

after my failed attempt at asking the question a few months back (not being detailed enough) - I'm going to try again.

Basically i'm attempting to develop a calculator for a game (RuneScape) this will determine the best order to use abilities in, each ability may have its own unique variables, some examples (these are actual abilities):

Order: Ability name, average (ability) damage, ability cooldown (time before it may be used again), adrenaline it may be used at (a bar that lies between 0 to 100, some abilities may be used at any and add 8 to the bar, others require, 50 or even 100 to be used and will remove 15/reset the bar to zero), time it takes to use ability, and finally I include any other special details.

Sever: 112.8 average damage, Cooldown: 15 seconds, used at any "adrenaline", giving +8, takes 1.8 seconds to execute

assault: 525.6 average damage, Cooldown: 30 seconds, used at 50 (or greater) adrenaline taking away -15, takes 4.2 seconds to execute.

Barge: 75 average damage, 20.4 second cooldown, used at any "adrenaline" giving +8, takes 1.8 seconds to execute, will bind the target for 6.6 seconds.

slice: 70 average damage, 3 second cooldown, used at any adrenaline giving +8, takes 1.8 seconds to execute, will deal (assume 1.5 - for simplicity) extra damage if the target is bound.

Now, lets say I wanted only a 6 second rotation (for simplicity), and started "adrenaline" at 50, there would be multiple ways to execute the abilities (for example):

1. Assault, followed by a sever
2. Barge, followed by a slice, followed by a sever, followed by a small assault.

etc ...

In this case, an algorithm could easily calculate which method is best using a brute-force algorithm and storing the best solution. However, given this is a simple example, If i wanted, say, 10 abilities over 18 seconds, brute force simply takes too long (unless anyone has a spare Quantum computer lying around). Other than checking random scenario's would anyone know a "heuristic" solution that may not always give the best results, but give close to best?

Further, here is a graph showing one simulation I did (not very pretty)
[image]

- Thanks to anyone who actually managed to read and understand my essay.

Comment: Did you try the brute force approach? I don't see that it would be infeasible, the skills you show have at least 3 seconds cooldown, permuting for example 6 things is not costly. If it turns out to be too much you could do a Monte Carlo approach, just stopping after you tried random combinations for some time.

Comment: A different note, you should look for a "steady state" damage output, the sequences you will find will always start with `assault` I guess, but you cannot chain such sequences because of other constraints. You want something periodic that you can repeat easily.

Comment: I mentioned above that this is a small example where brute force could be used, however when the inputs of abilities and times get larger, brute force simply takes too long.

Comment: abilities are user input, they can range anywhere from 1 to 10/11 (most commonly) up to a very maximum of slightly above 20 edit: and yes I have tried it out :)

Comment: Could you add the relevant code, I guess that will be the best to get new ideas from this site. Heuristics are highly dependent on the problem space, if you didn't find the thing that makes a good combination while working on it for months I doubt someone else will just snap a finger and find it. But there are experts here to speed things up significantly, at least you might be able to brute-force more skills.

Comment: I could, but it is rather messy right now, however I still can. How would you like me to share it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, that for different enemies the best sequence will differ. For example, if the enemy has medium defence, many HP and medium attacks, you need to make maximum damage/time for a long time. If another enemy has small HP and great attack, you should burst out for maximum damage, to kill him before he hits you. Great defense with medium attacks need very strong attacks from your side and collecting adrenaline for them and defensive tactics in between.

So, according to the enemy you should define the best one or two attacks or preprepaired combinations of actions. (let's name them attacks, too). This part should be solved by some complex if-then-else/case combination.  According to them you should plan the intermediate actions (by brute force combinatorics. The limit is only one - you should not die earlier. (of course, it could be changed in more complicated situation). What will be optimized - your adrenaline or HP in the end or time of the battle - it is up to you.

If combinatorics takes too much time, range optimization targets into several levels. Optimize for the highest level only for one time interval, fix results as the next start point, rerange optimization targets, optimize for the next time interval, and so on. This way we think in real life and it works fast and not so bad.